# How can I recursively call and redefine a function in elisp

Tags: elisp

I'm creating a collection of abbreviations which are tied to various elisp-functions.  The functions insert some text and define an interactive function called `ae-abbrev-next` which is mapped to the tab key.

For example, I've created an abbreviation `/int` which calls the function `ah-abbrev-insert-integral`; this function is defined as follows:

```
(defun ah-abbrev-insert-integral ()
  (ah-abbrev-insert-structure "\\int_{"    "}^{"    "}"    "\\mathrm{d}" ""))
```

What's supposed to happen is that when the abbreviation is expanded,

```
\int_{
```

is inserted into the buffer.  Then the function `ae-abbrev-next` is mapped to the `tab` key so that when `tab` is hit, the next string passed to `ah-abbrev-insert-structure` is inserted:

```
\int_{0 <TAB> }^{
```

Each time `<TAB>` is entered, it's calling a redefined `ae-abbrev-next`.

I've created some functions, macros, and variables which together achieve the effect that I want:

I've created an abbreviation which I've mapped to the following function

```
(defun ah-abbrev-insert-integral ()
  (ah-abbrev-insert-structure "\\int_{"    "}^{"    "}"    "\\mathrm{d}" ""))
```

Here is the rest of the code necessary to make this work:

```
(defmacro ah-abbrev-insert-structure
  (
   ae-string-a 
   ae-string-b 
   &optional 
   ae-string-c 
   ae-string-d
   ae-string-e
   )
  ;; round (1)          
  ;; insert front matter
  `(progn
     (insert ,ae-string-a)
     (ah-abbrev-set-mark-for-next)
     (defun z-abbrev-next ()
       ;; insert 2nd level material
       (ah-abbrev-search-for-next)
       (insert ,ae-string-b)
       ;; test whether 3rd level material
       (if (eq ,ae-string-c nil) (defun z-abbrev-next () (message "UNDEFINED"))
         (ah-abbrev-set-mark-for-next)
         (defun z-abbrev-next ()
           (ah-abbrev-search-for-next)
           (insert ,ae-string-c)
           ;; test whether 4th level material
           (if (eq ,ae-string-d nil) (defun z-abbrev-next () (message "UNDEFINED"))
             (ah-abbrev-set-mark-for-next)
             (defun z-abbrev-next ()
               (ah-abbrev-search-for-next)
               (insert ,ae-string-d)
               ;; test whether 5th level material
               (if (eq ,ae-string-e nil) (defun z-abbrev-next () (message "UNDEFINED"))
                 (ah-abbrev-set-mark-for-next)
                 (defun z-abbrev-next ()
                   (ah-abbrev-search-for-next)
                   (insert ,ae-string-e)
                   ;; no more options to test for
                   (defun z-abbrev-next () (message "UNDEFINED"))
                   ))
               ))
           ))
       )))


(defun ah-abbrev-set-mark-for-next ()
  (let ((ae-pos (point-marker)))
    (insert (concat "\n" ah-var-next-string))
    (goto-char ae-pos)))


(defun ah-abbrev-search-for-next ()
  (search-forward ah-var-next-string nil t)
  (replace-match "")
  (delete-char -1))

(defvar ah-var-next-string "%%/<next>/")

(defun ae-abbrev-next ()
  (interactive)
  (z-abbrev-next))
(defun z-abbrev-next () (message "UNDEFINED"))
```

All of the above works perfectly fine.
But I really want to create a version of `ah-abbrev-insert-structure` that recursively calls itself as follows.

Here's my attempt at making a recursive call:

```
(defun ah-abbrev-insert-structure ( ae-string-a &rest ae-string-b )
  (insert ae-string-a)
  (ah-abbrev-set-mark-for-next)
  (if (eq ae-string-b nil)
      (defun z-abbrev-next () (message "UNDEFINED"))
    (defun z-abbrev-next ()
      (ah-abbrev-search-for-next)
      (ah-abbrev-insert-structure ae-string-b))
  ))
```

The problem is `ae-string-b` is apparently unknown to `z-abbrev-next` when I later call it.  I get the following error message.

```
ae-abbrev-next: Symbol's value as variable is void: ae-string-b
```

I've tried rewriting `ah-abbrev-insert-structure` as a macro, but

```
(defun ah-abbrev-insert-structure ( ae-string-a &rest ae-string-b )
  `(progn
    (insert ,ae-string-a)
    (ah-abbrev-set-mark-for-next)
    (if (eq ,ae-string-b nil)
        (defun z-abbrev-next () (message "UNDEFINED"))
      (defun z-abbrev-next ()
        (ah-abbrev-search-for-next)
        (ah-abbrev-insert-structure ,ae-string-b))
    )))
```

But `elisp` really hates this.

How can I recursively call a function and redefine it?

Comment: A few comments: (1) `ae-string-b` will be a list (that's what `&rest` does), so you would want to use `apply` to call a function with the arguments in that list. (2) Your `variable is void` error is a standard matter of dynamic binding, and has nothing to do with redefining functions. (3) `defun` does not define a macro. (4) This approach seems crazy compared with storing the original list in a variable, and having your function (which you never redefine) read the next value from the list each time it's called.

Comment: @phils  I figured out since the posting that `ae-string-b` would be a list.  And I figured that I needed `apply`, but `apply` doesn't work on macros.  BUt I was able to get this to work in one context where I just nested the `(defun ...)`  And so in one context I was able to redfine my macro.  I also know I could store the variable content outside of the macro between calls; I would really like to know how to dynamically redefine the macro between those calls.